# Failed to load resource, blank page

Tags: javascript, php

Hi and thank you for looking at my question, I am currently having an issue with one of my forms displaying a white screen. I am getting the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500". What is happening is once my form is filled and you click on submit you are directed to this blank page instead of seeing a message that is supposed to be displayed, please find the code below:

```html
<?php
// Using PHP mailer from
$siteroot = "/home/externships/public_html" ;


//these are variables specific to the form
$usecsv = false;
//$csv_file = "test-student-mentor.csv";
$recipient1 = "example@mail.com";
//$recipient1 = "example@mail.com";

$sendtouser = false; // if true, send email to person who filled out form
$replyemail = "example@mail.com";

$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$formresults = '';

require_once ($siteroot . "/_include/formvalidator.php");
$validator = new FormValidator();

// Now, validate the form
if($validator->ValidateForm()) 
{

    $subject = $processed_form_variables['subject'];
    $redirect = $processed_form_variables['redirect'];
    unset($processed_form_variables['Submit']);
    unset($processed_form_variables['_pid']);
    unset($processed_form_variables['_fid']);
    unset($processed_form_variables['recipient']);
    unset($processed_form_variables['subject']);
    unset($processed_form_variables['redirect']);


    require_once ($siteroot . "/_include/form_results_for_email.php");

    $messagebody = "<p>You have a response from the Externship site " . $url . "</p><p>" . $formresults . "</p>";
    // send email via gmail
    require_once ($siteroot . "/_include/send_gmail.php");

    if(!$mail->Send()):
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        // else:                            // uncomment for testing
        //  echo "Message has been sent";   // uncomment for testing
    endif; 

    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: a HTTP 500 "internal server error" status indicates that your server-side script crashed somehow. Make sure you've got error logging switched in PHP and then run your code and check the logs to see error reports. That should give you a clue about what fix or further debugging you need to carry out.

Comment: I would setup an error log to help identify the source of the problem first

Comment: turn on error reporting

Comment: This is what I am getting:  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/externships/public_html/_phpgmailer/class.phpgmailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/externships/public_html/_include/send_gmail.php on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by you sending content when still wanting to send a header.
This will cause an error to be triggered along the lines of "Trying to modify header information with content already sent"

Put your redirect in the else part of your if statement and then exit.

```
    ....
    if(!$mail->Send()):
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        // else:                            // uncomment for testing
        //  echo "Message has been sent";   // uncomment for testing
    else:
        header("Location: $redirect");
    endif; 


    exit;
}
header("Location: $url");
```

You have error reporting disabled, which causes you not to see the error. Either look in the php error log, or turn it on in php.ini(`display_errors = on`) or use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in your php file at the start before executing the error code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I tried using your code but sadly still getting the same blank screen :(

Comment: This is what I am getting:  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/externships/public_html/_phpgmailer/class.phpgmailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/externships/public_html/_include/send_gmail.php on line 2

Comment: it can't find the file: `/home/externships/public_html/_phpgmailer/class.phpgmailer.php` make sure that is in the correct directory `_phpgmailer` because that's the include you defined in `send_gmail.php`

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.